# Greek characters problem - without Netbeans

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding, batch-file, java-io

in an application i write some strings into a file. Some of them are in greek language.
When i make this process with Netbeans, all work great. 
But when i try to run it with my .bat file, the same code writes the greek text with that strange "�?" character.
Obviously netbeans regulate something and it can writes the Greek text, but i can't find it.

Example of write:
`BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FilePath));
 out.write(text);
 out.close();`

The compile.bat and run.bat files are the simplest form they can get.

What can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to output in UTF-8 try:

```
try {
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream(FilePath), "UTF8"));
    out.write(text);
    out.close();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try it with that:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(yourFilePath,"UTF8"));
out.write(text); 
out.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say you see the Greek characters fine with NetBeans, you are probably writing output to the NetBeans console, which is a GUI window capturing standard output.  Windows generally has no problems rendering characters in these environments as the fonts are quite rich.

When you say you used a .BAT file, you were probably writing to the Windows *console* (`cmd.exe` or Powershell).  You can search for help on getting the Windows console to writing non-ASCII text; several sources exist that explain "code pages" and other things to know.  Basically it comes down to ensuring your console is set up properly.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching, I solved that problem.

In .bat file just put:

```
Set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS= -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this code solved it :

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding","UTF-8");
Field charset = Charset.class.getDeclaredField("defaultCharset");
charset.setAccessible(true);
charset.set(null,null);
```

[Setting the default Java character encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding)